# Can we replace Azure Portal by our enterprise Client app to perform all tasks that we perform on azure protal

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azureportal

Does Azure offer full APIs to accomplish all tasks without opening azure portal.
I heard some REST APIs are available but not sure about their coverage.

My questions is can we replace Azure portal completely by our customized enterprise App which actually calls REST APIs provided by Azure.

**here is Why I need this strange thing**

We need this as our organization is developing a Internal Unified App to manage our resources on all three cloud Azure,AWS and Google Cloud from single point..

Comment: See [Service Management REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx)

Comment: @AlexS We need this as our organization is developing a Internal Unified App to manage our resources on all three cloud Azure,AWS and Google Cloud from single point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. You can certainly do that. As Alex mentioned in his comments, take a look at [Azure Service Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) to begin with.

However there are a few things I would like to point out:

- As you know there are two portals right now ([Live](https://manage.windowsazure.com) and [Preview](https://portal.azure.com)). Unfortunately both of these portals use different sets of API. Live one uses [Service Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) and the Preview one uses [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx). So you have to make sure that you use both of these APIs in your application. Though Microsoft is pushing very hard to make all the APIs exposed through ARM API but there's still a lot of work that needs to be done.
- Another thing I noticed is that at times documentation for REST API for certain services is missing though there are ways to find that information. Just keep that in mind if you're building support for these services and not able to find documentation.

I would suggest you start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx and then find out REST APIs for the services you're interested in supporting in your application.